# Javascript print function causing colorbox window to shift left (IE)

Tags: javascript, colorbox

I'm trying to print the html page I display in my colorbox window but when I print them in IE anything it removes the padding to the left and shifts the window left. I've never seen this problem before. If someone can tell me how to stop this I would be much appreciative. Below is my code and here is the link to the page:

http://nsp.bionic-comms.co.uk/pmgf/page_ruth.html
(click on mumbai)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function printpage() {
    window.print();
}
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="printpage()"><img src="images/user_ruth/blogtitle.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: Well when you load it in IE, you get tons of 404's with png files.

Comment: I've fixed that now but that's not a helpful comment as it's not even related to the question I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the fix was as simple as using a jquery print function. Here's the link:

http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/easy-unobstructive-jquery-print-page-tutorial/